# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'

Tags: sql, databricks, repair

I want to run a repair job (MSCK REPAIR TABLE) in Azure Databricks, however I want to exclude 4 tables. What am I doing wrong?

```
database = "az_shffs"
tables = spark.catalog.listTables(database)

tables = tables.filter("tableName != 'exampletable1'").filter("tableName != 'exampletable2'").filter("tableName != 'exampletable3'").filter("tableName != 'exampletable4'")

for table in tables:
   spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {database}.{table.name}")`
```

I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'filter'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are storing the list of tables in in `tables` variable by running the following command `tables = spark.catalog.listTables(database)` but the variable type is `list` not `dataframe` and `list` has no attribute `filter`. If you still want to use filter then convert that to dataframe and then use filter.

Please refer below image.

[image]

You can use following command it will store that as a dataframe and then you can use filter.

```
df = spark.sql("show tables in demo")
display(df)
```

[image]

To run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE` command in for loop you can use below code.

`for i in tables.collect():`

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! Is there any way to filter a list without converting the list to a DataFrame?

Comment: I think you have to iterate through the list and remove the values which you won't need. Best way i would suggest is 
```df = spark.sql("show tables in demo")  df = df.filter("filter_condtion") for i in df.collect():  print(i)```

Comment: when doing so I´ll get the error: AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: Please provide error details with the code which you ran

Comment: database = "demo"
tables = spark.catalog.listTables(database)

tables = spark.sql("show tables in demo")

tables = tables.filter((tables.tableName  != "example1") & (tables.tableName  != "example2") & (tables.tableName  != "example3") & (tables.tableName  != "example4")) 

tables = df
for table in tables.collect():
   spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {database}.{table.name}"): AttributeError: name

Comment: Please use this in spark SQL command```spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {database}.{table["tableName"]}")```

Comment: SyntaxError: invalid syntax
  File "<command-2033459303290966>", line 2
    spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {database}.{table["tableName"]}")
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Use this spark.sql(f"MSCK REPAIR TABLE {database}.{table['tableName']}")

Comment: Please accept the answer so others can use